# Run a query where it displays records that have duplicate values across two columns but where it has distinct records on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, duplicates, distinct

I'm thinking something like this:

```
select column1, column2, count (*)
AND column3 is distinct
from table
group by column1, column2
having count(*) > 1
order by count (*) desc
```

obviously this is incorrect just not sure where to go from here, hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

In hindsight I should have clarified this a bit more. column1 and column2 are ClientID and PostalCode. column3 is name.

In most cases if ClientID and PostalCode are the same then Name will also be the same across all those records.
I need a query to display the cases where ClientID and PostalCode are the same but Name is varies.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Could you please add sample data and sample output for this?

Comment: And, tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Tell me if I understand your problem correctly, you want to get the records that appears on the both 2 columns?

Comment: it's hard to tell what you mean by "and column 3 is distinct". Do you simply want to do a distinct count? In other words:   count(distinct column3) as unique_count

Comment: @user3930324 the query I posted will do what you describe. You could also list the values in that third column (on the same row) using various functions such as group_concat, listagg, string_agg, etc. but you tagged multiple databases in your question. If you specify what database you're actually using we can tell you what function to use to identify the unique values in a horizontal, aggregated list (on one row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is most likely what you want, based more on the title of your question:

```
select column1,
       column2,
       count(distinct column3) as num_duplicates
  from table
 group by column1, column2
having count(distinct column3) > 1
 order by 3 desc
```